# How can I debug my Android native C++ library for Unity3D?

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, juce

I have created a JUCE based audio library in C++ (originally as a windows DLL)

I have successfully built it into an AAR library with Android Studio

I can successfully run it in a Unity3D build for Android.

I can get the debugger messages back to LogCat

However, I really need to step through some part of the native C++ code with a managed debugger.  ( I know how use a debugger for the c# for unity )

I've searched for days but cannot find an answer.

---

Unity3D 2018.3.11f1

Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0